# Proper way to distribute packages

Tags: python, docker, compilation, raspberry-pi, arm

I am trying to run a python script on a several raspberry pis that requires a few modules which have not been updated to their latest version on apt nor on pip. Specifically I am looking at opencv and gstreamer. I can (in theory) compile them on the pi but it can take a long time and I don't want to compile it on every pi (which can take a while). I also want to distribute this code to others. What would be the right way to get these packages on the raspberry pi?

Should I look into docker, should I just copy the binaries from one pi to another? Should I compile it on a vm such as qemu?

Any ideas?

EDIT: Found this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=8478

Compiling now, lets see what happens!

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat, but have you considered distributing your script with the appropriate wheels (.whl) for the packages you need?

Comment: @Grismar I have not considered this. I have never used wheels before.